# Unable to set .net core 3.1 to Blazor Webassembly client and shared projects

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, asp.net-blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-core-sdk

I installed Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.6.1 (the latest update) at `B:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community` on  a Windows 10 x64 bit.
Afterwards, I also installed `dotnet-sdk-3.1.300-win-x64.exe` with its default path `C:\Program Files\dotnet`.  They are in different drives.

I create  new Blazor Webassembly projects consisting of

- `ProjectName.Server` with target framework set to .net core 3.1 by default.
- `ProjectName.Shared` with target framework set to .net core 2.1 by default.
- `ProjectName.Client` with target framework set to .net core 2.1 by default.

I attempted to change the last two projects above to .net core 3.1 but the target framework dropdown does not provide me with .net core 3.1 option.

## Question

Why is there no .net core 3.1 option available to choose? What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProjectName.Shared` and `ProjectName.Client` are .Net Standart and that is not .Net Core